# I want to dialogflow custom payload response to be shown as clickable text button (i.e upon click it should return msg with same text, same as chips)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want the functionality of Dialogflow custom payload chips but just wanted to make it's width to cover the full line[image: similar to attached picture i want the display, to be similar to the picture and want functionality similar to Dialogflow chip]

***Summary:***
I want a button that covers the width of the chatbot and upon click, it should return the value (which is return in it) as msg.

I am using custom payload in the Dialogflow console.